# Likelihood of finding a matching hash

Tags: hash

Lets assume someone gained access to a server and was able to gather the usernames and the password hashes from the database.

What is the likelihood of being able to find a match using rainbow table attacks ? How would you rate such a situation ? Low ? Medium ? Critical ? What would be the steps to recover from such attack?

Comment: What sort of hashes? Are they hashes of passwords? Are they salted? Are the contents of the hashes stored next to them in the database in an easily matched form? All of these are possible, and have an effect on the risk level.

Comment: @Matthew Thank you for your replay. I see now that there are many factors that one would have to take into account.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the likelihood of being able to find a match using rainbow table attacks?**

This depends on the type of hash algorithm that is used and the complexity of the password policy (if there is one).

**How would you rate such a situation?**

This depends on how you obtained the hashes. Obviously there is a cause to obtaining these hashes. The cause should be considered at least high in my opinion, the effect is you being able to retrieve usernames and password hashes.

**What would be the steps to recover from such attack?**

This depends on what caused you being able to retrieve this information.
I recommend it to put it as one (at least) high finding in your report.